# Enumerated list with circle around using tikz still problem

Tags: tikz-pgf, enumerate, babel

I was facing problem with enumerate list decorated with `tikz` in `babel` package environment. The problem is asked [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/620747/enumerated-list-with-circle-around-using-tikz/) and got an idea of solving it. But still a new problem is occurred which is shown in the figure.

[image]

In the figure, you will see *bangla* character is **not synced together**. There **should not contain a gap** in between (highlighted in the figure). How can I remove or overcome it keeping `babel` environment and others settings same?

It should be something like this:

[image]

**For your understanding, my MWE:**

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\babelprovide[import, onchar = fonts ids]{bengali}
% \babelfont[bengali]{rm}[Renderer=Harfbuzz]{FreeSerif}
\babelfont[bengali]{rm}[Renderer=Harfbuzz,AutoFakeBold,AutoFakeSlant=0.3]{Kalpurush}
\babelcharproperty{`।}{locale}{bengali}

% bangla numerals
\babelprovide[maparabic,alph=alphabetic]{bengali}

% draw figures
\usepackage{tikz}

% circled numbering
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newcommand*\circled[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{%
            \node[shape=circle,fill=black!20,inner sep=2pt] (char) {#1};}}

\begin{document}

\subsubsection*{গণিতের চারটি নিয়ম}
\begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=*,label=\foreignlanguage{bengali}{\protect\circled{\arabic*}}]

    \item যোগের জন্য দেওয়া সংখ্যাগুলোর যেকোন একটিকে অথবা দুটিকেই কাছাকাছি কোন রাউন্ড ফিগার করে নিই। কোন সংখ্যাকে রাউন্ড করতে হলে তার সাথে অন্য একটি ছোট সংখ্যা যোগ বা বিয়োগ করে তাকে ১০ এর গুণিতক আকারে লিখি। 
    \item এবার রাউন্ড করা সংখ্যার সাথে অন্য সংখ্যাটি সহজেই যোগ করে ফেলি। যোগের সময় রাউন্ড করতে নেওয়া অতিরিক্ত সংখ্যাটি আলাদা রাখি।
\end{enumerate}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks to `@JasperHabicht` and `@Javier Bezos`.

Comment: I can't test it because I don't have the font, but is this indeed related to TikZ or enumerate? In other words, does it display correctly if you put only the text in a document, without the list environment? If it also does not work in that case then you could simplify the example code to focus the problem more and make the search for a solution easier.

Comment: You don't need the font, its already incorporate with `babel`. Experts say its related to tikz. (See comments of previous problem, link in description). 

Yeah, it displays correctly if I put only the text in a document.

Comment: @Masudur I’ve edited the answer to the original question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/620825/5735 .